# Is there a connection between complex tori and ideal class group of quadratic number fields?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, complex-geometry

Let $K$ be a quadratic number field and $O_K$ the relative integer ring. Then the ideal class group $\mathcal{H}_K$ might be seen as the quotient set of the fractional ideals of $O_K$ by the relation
$ \mathcal{A} \sim \mathcal{A}'  \iff \exists\lambda\in \mathbb{C}^* \ : \mathcal{A} = \lambda\mathcal{A}'$ (and the product rule comes from ideal multiplication). In this situation, ideals of $O_K$ may be seen as lattices in $\mathbb{C}$.

Further, it's well known that the complex tori $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ and $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda'$, where $\Lambda$ and $\Lambda'$ are lattices, are isomorphic if and only if $\exists\lambda\in \mathbb{C}^* \ : \Lambda = \lambda\Lambda'$.

Thus, it seems to me that to every element in $\mathcal{H}_K$ corresponds an unique isomorphism class of complex tori. Is it true? And if so, are there any other deeper connections?

Comment: What you want is called the theory of complex multiplication: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_multiplication

Comment: For *imaginary* quadratic fields, yes.  The real quadratic setting is much more difficult and questions that are settled in the imaginary quadratic case are still open in the real quadratic case.